# Simple console text editor suited to python

Tags: terminal, python, editors

I am looking for a light weight shell editor for Linux that a young child (eg 7-8 year old) can write python scripts in.

The motivation is to find something that is helpful for a beginning programmer without the frustrations of a steep learning curve.

It needs to accomplish the following:

1. Simple interface like joe, pico etc.
2. No complicated modes to think about like vim and emacs.
3. Can be configured to turn tabs into whitespace for python.
4. Ideally it should have some syntax colouring features.
5. Must have a way to configure a hotkey to run the current
   script.

To clarify what I mean by the last point, my .vimrc file has these lines which allow me to press  to execute the current script.

```
autocmd BufRead *.py set makeprg=python\ -c\ \"import\ py_compile,sys;\ sys.stderr=sys.stdout;\ py_compile.compile(r'%')\"
autocmd BufRead *.py set efm=%C\ %.%#,%A\ \ File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%.%#,%Z%[%^\ ]%\\@=%m
autocmd BufRead *.py nmap <F5> :!python %<CR>
```

Comment: is the console mode of editor a necessary requirement? if it does not you should look at gui like bluefish or geany

Comment: You might want to rethink the syntax colouring, especially for a child. They have better eyesight than you or I, and if this is a learning experience then actually learning to have mistakes jump out at you (as a side effect of learning python) will help them in all aspects of life. So instead of thinking "why isn't this word coloured like I think it should be" they will be thinking "where is my missing close-paren" (OK, Python: where is my missing close-quote).

Comment: I'm predominantly interested in a console solution. Ultimately being able to run programs on a remote server is exciting and the same problem comes up with advocating python to SysAdmins who aren't good with emacs or vim.

Comment: Syntax colouring is less important than the other criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pywarrior is a good fit:

http://www.mindspring.com/~torajima/pywarrior/pywarrior.html

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Jethro, this is tantalisingly close to what I am looking for. I'll confirm if I can work around the gnome-terminal dependency. But thanks a lot for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

MIT recommends IDLE for their [6.01](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/software-and-tools/) class. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) has a nice description and should fill all of your requirements. Official documentation for [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html).

Comment: The OP wanted console editor, and IDLE is gui editor.